# How to assign values of y to a new column named y2 when x has duplicate values

Tags: r, dataframe, transform

I am investigating dairy stable types which have a certain code. I want to display, per farm, which types of stables there are present. In my data, every stable has it's own row, so there are multiple rows per farm when a farm has multiple stables. But I want to transform it so that every farm has one row, and each stable has it's own column.

| Farm ID | Stable type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A10 |
| 1 | A20 |
| 1 | A30 |
| 2 | A10 |
| 2 | A20 |
| 3 | A10 |

Desired output =

| Farm ID | Stable1 | Stable2 | Stable3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A10 | A20 | A30 |
| 2 | A10 | A20 | NA |
| 3 | A10 | NA | NA |

---

Comment: use `pivot_wider` from the `tidyr` package

Comment: Here's all you need: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html, and welcome to stack overflow.

Comment: With `library(dplyr)` and `library(tidyr)` you can do `your_data |> mutate(row_id = row_number(), .by = FarmID) |> pivot_wider(names_from = row_id, values_from = Stable_type, names_prefix = "Stable")`, updating to your actual data and column names, of course.

Comment: Hi, you're looking into reshaping your data structure from long format to wide format. There are several functions that can do this and it has been asked before (by many others, too), so this is a duplicated question. Here is a link to the same question with many solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890584/6288065